# how to hide and show button on excel ribbon using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins, excellibrary, pyxll

Hii guys I am working a excel addin project which add custom ribbon using the [ribbon xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019#RibbonDescriptorFile) structure defined by microsoft. I have 2 button on this ribbon login and logout .Now when the excel load I want to show login button only and when user login hide login button and show logout button . Now the challange is I need this changes to take place at runtime when excel is running . and I unable to get any reference for this hide and show functionality

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="Tab1" label="Add-in">
            <group id="Tools" label="Tools">
                <button id="Login" label="Login"/>
                <button id="Logout" label="Logout"/>
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

Although the project is in python using pyxll addin but any VBA solution can also be incorporated. I am unable to find any article or reference for my problem so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm#:~:text=To%20be%20able%20to%20Hide,we%20want%20to%20make%20visible.

Comment: Thanks siddhart combination of getVisible and Invalidate(from your link) did solve the problem.... Thank You